# Schedule refresh not working for web.contents based query

Tags: api, powerbi

This is the message I get when I am trying to get the token data using web.contents query from "VMware vRealize Automation API":

> There was an error when processing the data in the dataset.
>   Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
>   Data source error
>
> {"error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","pbi.error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","parameters":
>   {},"details":[{"code":"Message","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com/identity/api/tokens' 
>   (404): Not Found"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
>
> Table: GetToken.

The url passed to the first parameter of Web.Contents `(authUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/identity/api/tokens")` is accessible but always return the `HTTP ERROR 405`, probably 
because this API uses a a JSON object in the request body parameter with the users credentials to obtain the Response.

API

[image]

My query

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main issues:

1. Your API uses `HTTP POST` verses `GET`, so you need to set `Options[Content]`
2. You can get refresh errors on the service unless you use `Options[RelativePath]`
3. You can "opt-in" to handling errors for specific HTTP Status codes, combined with `Value.MetaData` you get more detailed error messages.
4. Let it generate JSON for you from `record`s and `list`s by using `Query` or `Content` parameters see: [docs: Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents)

This is equivalent to your `curl` POST request

```
let
    BaseUrl = "https://www.example.com",
    Options = [
        RelativePath = "/identity/api/tokens",
        Headers = [
            Accept="application/json"
        ],
        Content = [
            username = "username",
            password = "password",
            tenant = "tenant"
        ],
        ManualStatusHandling = {400, 405}
    ],
    // wrap 'Response' in 'Binary.Buffer' if you are using it multiple times
    response = Web.Contents(BaseUrl, Options),
    buffered = Binary.Buffer(response),
    response_metadata = Value.Metadata(response),
    status_code = response_metadata[Response.Status],
    from_json = Json.Document(final_result)
in
    from_json
```

I have related `Web.Contents` examples here, like Chaining `Web.Contents` requests: [ninmonkeys.com/Power-Query-Custom-Functions-Cheat-Sheet](https://ninmonkeys.com/blog/2021/01/31/power-query-custom-functions-cheat-sheet/#Chaining_WebContents_to_Merge_Many_Queries)